# Python append value to list of unique objects

Tags: python, excel, list, pandas, append

Please forgive any naiveté in this question. I have been actively trying to form a rudimentary understanding of programming over the last few months. There are many gaps, so I may not know what I don't know.

The dataset I am working with is currently in excel, so VBA might be a good option, however I would like to use this as an opportunity to use Python. I would import the data as a CSV and then manipulate it. This seems well suited for a panda dataframe...

I have a list objects, each with several named values:

```
 Object Name | Value Name  | Value        |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| a1         |        top1 |     20     
| a1         |        top2 |     30
| a1         |        top3 |     65
| a2         |        top1 |     28      
| a2         |        top2 |     32
| a3         |        top1 |     89
| a3         |        top2 |     120
| a3         |        top3 |     160
...
```

In a separate list, I have an additional value for each object

```
 Object Name | Value Name  | Value        |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| a1         |        base |     99     
| a2         |        base |     250
| a3         |        base |     600
| a4         |        base |     87
| a5         |        base |     1202
| a6         |        base |     58
...
```

I would like to append the new value/value-name for each object.

The output should look something like this (asterisks denotes appended values):

```
 Object Name | Value Name  | Value        |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| a1         |        top1 |     20     
| a1         |        top2 |     30
| a1         |        top3 |     65
| a1 *       |        base |     99
| a2         |        top1 |     28      
| a2         |        top2 |     32
| a2 *       |        base |     250
| a3         |        top1 |     89
| a3         |        top2 |     120
| a3         |        top3 |     160
| a3 *       |        base |     600
```

in a very rough sense, this is what I would like to accomplish:

```
for each object in objects:
    if df_Objects[ObjectName] = df_Object_Base[ObjectName]:
        df_Objects = df_Objects + {Value_Name, Value}
```

I have only recently succeeded in installing pandas, but I have not put it to much use. The end goal will be to export the modified data back out as a CSV. If you have a more simple approach, I would be very open to seeing it.

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting to merge two dataframes based on a column, though it's not entirely clear. It may clarify the question if you were to include an example of what the output should look like.

Comment: @johnchase the question has been edited to show the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @johnchase for providing the insight to find a solution to this question.

The correct methodology, if using a DataFrame, is outlined [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

I was attempting to join two dataframes on a column (example from above link):

```
>>> A              >>> B
lkey value         rkey value
0   foo  1         0   foo  5
1   bar  2         1   bar  6
2   baz  3         2   qux  7
3   foo  4         3   bar  8
```

-

```
>>> merge(A, B, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey', how='outer')
lkey  value_x  rkey  value_y
0  foo   1        foo   5
1  foo   4        foo   5
2  bar   2        bar   6
3  bar   2        bar   8
4  baz   3        NaN   NaN
5  NaN   NaN      qux   7
```

From here exporting out as a csv using pandas should be a pretty straightforward operation.

Thank you